How can fastreport send values ​in Edit to parameters in an SQL?
I have the editable field "Edit1" I want to enter the values ​​to be filtered in a sql with a comma as shown in the image

The value send to Query


When I type a value it works, but when I type more values ​​separated by a comma it doesn't return any value, does anyone know why?

You can't pass a comma separated list as a parameter.
Pass in the list as a string and use a function like the one described here
to split the list into integers and which you can use in a join.
